# How to calculate the sum of the absolute value of integers in a list?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I tried to calc the sum of the abs value of nums in a list like this:

```
stage = sum(sum(abs(board))) # board is a list named before
```

it returned "bad operand type for abs(): 'list'"

so I tried using map like:

```
tmp = list(map(abs,board))
```

however, the error information remains the same.
What can I do?

The statements using the sum of 'board' are shown as following:

```
stage = sum(sum(board))
colfull = numpy.zeros((8, 8), dtype=numpy.int64)
colfull[:,numpy.sum(map(abs,board), axis = 0) == 8] = True
```

Comment: Those errors don't seem to match the snippets. In the first one, `abs()` isn't being called. I think you actually ran `sum(abs(board))`. In the second, there shouldn't be an error, but you're not calculating the sum. Now, it's obvious what you're trying to do, but in the future, it will help to provide a [mre]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 3):

You need `map` (to map the `abs`) and `sum` (to sum the values). Hence

```
tmp = sum(map(abs, board))
```

Comment: I feel sorry to say that the error still exists and I'm quite confused(facepalm)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a generator expression passed to `sum()`:

```py
stage = sum(abs(x) for x in board)
```

You can read more about generator expressions in the original [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#abstract).

Comment: Note that this constructs an unnecessary intermediate list, whereas `map` (or just removing the brackets from the comprehension) ensures that the values are only summed, and no additional memory is required for the intermediary.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @SilvioMayolo! Would a generator expression be more appropriate then?

Comment: A generator expression should be relatively equal in performance to my answer on Python 3.

Comment: Thx for your response but I've tried this way and the error remains the same...

Comment: Then there's something going on in your code that you haven't shown us. If `board` is a list of numbers (or number-like entities) then the code snippet provided will sum their absolute values correctly.

Comment: thx for reminding I've added the statements in the question

Comment: @2e8 But what is `board`? Please provide a [mre] like I mentioned.

Comment: Here is a function returning board: def getNewBoard():
    board = numpy.zeros((8, 8), dtype=numpy.int64)
    return board